# Add object to animation (Holding an Axe in Hand)

Tags: animation

Can I add a object to the animation without to animate it so it just moves with the other transform or is this not a thing in blender?

[image]

I want to add this axe to my player model and to make it so it moves with the characters animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can give your axe a *Child Of* constraint with the hand bone as *Target*, or select your axe, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *(Parent) > Bone*.

Comment: Thanks this perfectly worked. I just made the axe a child of the hand bone. Again thank you so much :)

Comment: While parenting does make your prop move with your hand, I recommend you to use constraints instead. As parenting lacks several controls constraints have like the ability to blend different parents or toggle ability over time

Comment: he could also give a Child Of constraint to the hand instead, with the axe as Target, then move the axe instead of the hand