# Attach “axe” to bone in Blender Python API

Tags: bones, transforms

I’d like to do something like this, but with the Blender Python API, as I am writing an importer.  Ideally, I would attach a transformation to a bone, and attach a shape or geometry to the transformation.

[Add object to animation (Holding an Axe in Hand)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234434/add-object-to-animation-holding-an-axe-in-hand)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to attach an object to a bone. The simplest is bone parenting. The script below should do it.

```py
import bpy

# Get the armature object using its object name.
arm = bpy.data.objects['Rig']
# Get the active bone. I assume the weapon needs to be attached to this bone. If the name of the bone is known, this step can be skipped.
bone = arm.data.bones.active
# Get the active object. I assume the active object is the weapon.
obj = bpy.context.active_object

# Modify the parenting parameters to achieve bone parenting.
obj.parent = arm # Armature object
obj.parent_bone = bone.name # Bone name
obj.parent_type = 'BONE'
```

This will place the weapon at the tip of the bone and orient it to match the bone orientation. If this is not the desired position and orientation, you will have to modify the weapon transforms.

If you already prepared a setup where the weapon just needs to be parented to a proxy object (for example, an *Empty*), you can use object parenting which is simpler as shown below.

```py
import bpy

empty = bpy.data.objects['Empty']
obj = bpy.context.active_object

obj.parent = empty
```